# how can I route static inside react component on Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I have link like `/abc` under static folder, how can I use react to Link it?

I have tried Link component, but was failed.

```
import Link from "@docusaurus/Link";
```

Should be something related `pathname://` protocal.